# Why can't I increment std::unordered_map iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, increment, unordered-map

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> _cache;

std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator> _lruList;
```

this works

`std::rotate(_lruList.begin(), _lruList.begin() + 1, _lruList.end());`

but this doesn't

`std::rotate(_cache.begin(), _cache.begin() + 1, _cache.end()); // error occurs on _cache.begin() + 1 saying "error type"`

Which doesn't really make sense to me because they are both iterators except one is for a `vector` and one is for a `unordered_map`

Then I also tried this
`std::rotate(_cache.begin(), _cache.begin() ++, _cache.end());`

but I got the following errors:
`_Left: you can't assign to a variable that is const`
`_Right: you can't assign to a variable that is const`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unordered_map` iterators are forward iterators. That means they can only move one step at a time, only forward, and getting from one position to another requires traversing all of the intervening positions. As such, forward iterators do not support `operator+`, because it would be an O(n) operation. The authors of the standard library felt that when people see `a + b`, they expect that to be O(1), and so if an iterator type can't meet that requirement, then the operator should not be supported.

`vector` iterators are random access, which means they do support `operator+`, because it can be implemented as O(1). You can do this instead:

```
std::rotate(_cache.begin(), std::next(_cache.begin()), _cache.end());
```

Except that also won't work, because `std::rotate` is a modifying operation. And you can't modify the keys of elements in `unordered_map`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: Why are you allowed to use `++` on a forward iterator but not `+1`?

Comment: @Iamanon You can't overload a function based on a value, only based on a type. So you can't allow `+1` without also allowing `+1000`. And the reason that's not allowed is explained in my answer.